# Is there student dorm accommodation in Leipzig (Germany) for non-students?

Tags: budget, accommodation, germany, leipzig

I'm intending to spend this summer in Leipzig, Germany and I'm searching for an accommodation. My friends were in Stuttgart and they managed to find a good place in Kolping House in Stuttgart, which provides dorm accommodation also for non-students. It was relatively cheap and good.

I wonder if there are similar options in Leipzig (accommodation in cheap student dorms not affiliated to a university).

Comment: As it stands, this question can only be answered by people who have actually been to the Kolping House, whatever that may be.  Could you perhaps explain more specifically what you are looking for in an accommodation?

Comment: yes accommodation in student Dorms not affiliated to a university

Comment: rent is so much cheaper in Leipzig than in Stuttgart. You'll be fine finding a cheap place to stay.

Comment: Are these the things called "Studentenhotels" or something similar in German? I remember staying in one of those a decade ago somewhere travelling in Germany. Or is it something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no Kolping houses in Leipzig, and hardly any in eastern Germany as such. You will have to find an alternative.

The biggest student accomodation in Leipzig is [organized by the University](http://www.studentenwerk-leipzig.de/wohnen/onlinebewerbung), but you need to prove that you are studying in Leipzig before you get a room there.

Another solution is the "[Evangelische Studienhaus](http://www.ev-studienhaus-leipzig.de/2.php)" which is however strongly religious (reformed) and they are not really clear if you need to be a student to live there.

You best bet might be one called [Youniq](http://www.youniq-group.de/de/Projekte/Studentenwohnungen/Leipzig.html), which is more of an independent company running student homes (also as a investment opportunity). They operate [3 houses in Leipzig](http://www.youniq.de/en/How-to-rent/), and do so also for non-students, with a special [FAQ for those](http://downloads.youniq.de/?f=YOUNIQ-SVC-EN-Leipzig-Information-Form-Non-Student-2013-02-17.pdf) and the whole website is available in English.

Comment: The biggest student accomodation you mentioned is organised by Studentenwerk, not University. Also, I remember, that I was able to rent a room there for several days for my father, although he obviously was not a student.